# Why is the canonical projection map $\pi_S$ not injective?

Tags: linear-algebra

I can't wrap my head around the fact that $\pi_S$ is not injective. When proving the correspondence theorem for vector spaces, we have to prove that $\pi_S$ is bijective and hence we have to not only prove surjectivity but also injectivity. The theorem is as follows:

> Suppose $S\subset V$ is a subspace. Then, for all subspaces $T$ s.t. $S\subset T\subset V$, there exists an order-preserving (w.r.t. set inclusion) bijection $\pi_S:T\to T/S$.

Here's a proof of injectivity:

Suppose $S\subset T_1\subset T_2\subset V$. We want to prove that $T_1/S = T_2/S \implies T_1 = T_2$.

$T_1/S = T_2/S \implies \exists t_1\in T_1 \land \exists t_2\in T_2$ s.t. $t_1 + S = t_2 + S \subset T_2\implies t_1\in T_2 \implies T_1\subset T_2$. The proof for $T_2\subset T_1$ is analogous. Thus $T_1 = T_2$ and $\pi_S$ is injective.

But why is $\pi_S$ only injective in the context of the correspondence theorem?

Comment: Take T=S, then $T/S$ and $\pi_S$ are trivial, and so the map can't be injective (unless T is 0-dimensional, but that's not the point).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\pi_S$, as a specific linear map $T\to T/S$, is almost never injective. It injects iff. $S$ is the zero subspace. Your notation makes the reader think this is what you claim.

However, reading your post, what I think you really mean is: the assignment $\{\text{subspaces $T$ of $V$ containing $S$}\}\to\{\text{subquotients of $V$}\}$, $T\mapsto T/S$, is injective.

So we are in the unfortunate notational situation where $T\mapsto T/S$ is genuinely injective as a function of $T$ but the maps $T\to T/S$ are not injective. Crucial difference between $\mapsto$ and $\to$ !

Comment: Reading your answer and re-reading some sections of the textbook I'm consulting, things are more clear now. Thank you.